# How to create dynamic class names for ul?

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists

I want to achieve the result that each ul should have different/dynamic class names and it should be unique. Below is my code but its not working as per the expectation.

```js
document
  .querySelectorAll(".main-nav > .main-nav-list")
  .forEach((element) => {
    element.setAttribute("class", `${element.className} hasChild top`);
    element.querySelectorAll("li > ul").forEach((subElement) => {
      subElement.setAttribute("class", `${subElement.className} hasChild sub`);
    });
  });
```

```html
<nav class="main-nav">
   <ul class="main-nav-list">
       <li class="a"> <a href="/">First</a>
           <ul class="main-nav-list">
               <li class="b"> <a href="/">Type of menu</a>
                   <ul class="main-nav-list">
                       <li class="c"> <a href="/">Summer</a> </li>
                       <li class="c"> <a href="/">Winter</a> </li>
                       <li class="c"> <a href="/">All season</a> </li>
                       <li class="c"> <a href="/">Spring </a> </li>
                   </ul>
               </li>
           </ul>
       </li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

I would like to have guidance to resolve this. Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use number of index, just add `(index,element)` and use index how different for example the ul will be `1-youclassname, 2-yourclassname ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the most simple way to achive what you want

```
var ul = document.querySelectorAll(".main-nav ul")
ul.forEach((each,i)=>{
    each.classList.add("ul-"+i)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Now in the below snippet if you check, you can see all the UL has a unique class name. I created a random number in the range and appending that with a string to make as class name

```js
var data = document
  .querySelectorAll(".main-nav .main-nav-list");
  
  data.forEach((element) => {
    element.setAttribute("class", `list_${parseInt(Math.random() * (1000 - 0) + 0)} hasChild top`);
    console.log(element.className);
  });
```

```html
<nav class="main-nav">
   <ul class="main-nav-list">
       <li class="a"> <a href="/">First</a>
           <ul class="main-nav-list">
               <li class="b"> <a href="/">Type of menu</a>
                   <ul class="main-nav-list">
                       <li class="c"> <a href="/">Summer</a> </li>
                       <li class="c"> <a href="/">Winter</a> </li>
                       <li class="c"> <a href="/">All season</a> </li>
                       <li class="c"> <a href="/">Spring </a> </li>
                   </ul>
               </li>
           </ul>
       </li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to change the ULs you can do this

Note the […spread] is optional. Older Edge browsers do not support forEach on a nodeList

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll(".main-nav ul")]
  .forEach((element,i) => {
    element.classList.add("hasChild", "top", `c${new Date().getTime()}`);
  });
```

```html
<nav class="main-nav">
  <ul class="main-nav-list">
    <li class="a"> <a href="/">First</a>
      <ul class="main-nav-list">
        <li class="b"> <a href="/">Type of menu</a>
          <ul class="main-nav-list">
            <li class="c"> <a href="/">Summer</a> </li>
            <li class="c"> <a href="/">Winter</a> </li>
            <li class="c"> <a href="/">All season</a> </li>
            <li class="c"> <a href="/">Spring </a> </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: `querySelectorAll` already returns an array why are you spreading it into new array then using `foreach` on it

Comment: It returns a nodeList and not an array. Older versions of edge do not support forEach on a nodeList and if I want to use map or filter instead I would have to spread anyway

Answer (score 0):

```js
const ulNode = document.querySelectorAll('.main-nav .main-nav-list')

ulNode.forEach((parent, i) => {
    for (let j = 0; j < parent.children.length; j++) {
        parent.children[j].classList.add(`ok-${i + 1}`)
        console.log(parent.children);
    }
});
```

```html
<nav class="main-nav">
   <ul class="main-nav-list">
       <li class="a"> <a href="/">First</a>
           <ul class="main-nav-list">
               <li class="b"> <a href="/">Type of menu</a>
                   <ul class="main-nav-list">
                       <li class="c"> <a href="/">Summer</a> </li>
                       <li class="c"> <a href="/">Winter</a> </li>
                       <li class="c"> <a href="/">All season</a> </li>
                       <li class="c"> <a href="/">Spring </a> </li>
                   </ul>
               </li>
           </ul>
       </li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

This worked for me.